# TCPListener behind router(port forwarded) not working for me

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, router, tcplistener

If I connect my pc directly to internet everything is ok, however with my router connected the following code get stuck in readline:

`

```
TcpListener webserver = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1302);
webserver.Start(); 
Debug.WriteLine("Started");
TcpClient client = webserver.AcceptTcpClient();
Debug.WriteLine("Client accepted");
sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream()); 
   try
  {
      string req = sr.ReadLine();
      Debug.WriteLine("Request: " + req);
      if (req != null)
      { 
        //HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n
        //+read file to tcpstream
      }`
```

I'm not trying to build a webserver I'm just testing things out with tcp.
If I use http://192.168.1.100:1302/ in a webbrowser or my public IP without the router the webpage loads so I'm guessing it's sg to do with my router or do I have to implement something else?
What I'm seeing is:

1. readline is stuck(If I refresh the page a few times the GET / HTTP/1.1 gets trough)
   If I use read() I see a load of -1
2. I used wireshark and I'm seeing a lot of greyed out packages and a lot of retransmissions:
   [wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkW7A.png)

I'm stuck first I thought I have to implement Upnp or nat punch through, but since some things are getting through I don't think establishing the connection is the problem.

Why are there packet losts? Where should I even start to debug the problem?

UPDATE #1: 
The client(chrome webbrowser) is the same computer, but I tried outside computers(with and without behind a router) as well same result.

UPDATE #2: I think I might know what the problem is, I just tried an external webpage tester and there were no problems, so far every device was in the same ISP. I have to try it with vpn or a device that is outside of my ISP network.

Comment: Have you enabled port forwarding of 1302 in the router?

Comment: Yes, both (tcp and udp)

Comment: Yeah, now I see that in the title. It is unclear to me where the client connection is originating from which should be connecting. I assumed that you were on a public IP outside the firewall. I would expect that the ReadLine is making a blocking call, waiting for a line of data from the client session. But, there is not enough code here to sort that bit out.

Comment: Have you actually tried to even stating the computer’s IP on DMZ? Just to make sure it’s not a port-forwarding thing instead of a coding issue. And try disabling firewall/antivirus and so on.

Comment: JamieMeyer I updated the question, the code doesn't do anything else really reads a file and responds with HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n which doesn't even happen after that it would send the file. In the wireshark I didn't wanted to include my public ip for safety reason, but I could replce it with tags. Oh yeah the code is in a thread, but that's all. @Gonzo345 Yes I tried DMZ same thing happens, I tried firewall and antivirus that was the first thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is normal or not, but because of packet loss most packets never arrives to my application. This problem is defently caused by my router(and maybe sg. else), but I even tried to connect to my app with other devices in the same ISP same problem. I confirmed this by using vpn and also with another computer using different ISP.